# Is it against Minecraft's TOS to play Splitscreen on PC?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, legal

I've found a way to play splitscreen on Minecraft PC thanks to the internet where I run the game twice or thrice on the same computer on the same account but just change the name of the player in notepad.

I've got two copies of the bedrock edition on PS3 and PS4 and the splitscreen is dull without mods so I want to play splitscreen on PC with my friends in a few days. They have copies of the bedrock edition too.

I've looked at the EULA and saw this:

"This also means you cannot sell or rent the Game, or make it available for access to other people"

"let other people get access to anything we've made in a way that is unfair or unreasonable"

https://account.mojang.com/documents/minecraft_eula

Does this mean I can't do splitscreen with my friends? I've sent Mojang a support ticket which is taking ages, probably half a month for them to reply.

Here is a Minecraft PC splitscreen in the picture, I've used the joypad mod for controller. This is a test, my friends weren't playing here.

[image]

Comment: What now, MCPE or MCJava? You keep mentioning MCPE, but the screenshots show MCJava.

Comment: It's MCJAVA with three of the same legit account modded to help splitscreen. I've brought up MC Bedrock edition ( Any Minecraft version found on consoles) because it has splitscreen yet doesn't have modability which royally sucks. It's just that many of me and my friends have bought several copies of this game and I don't want to have to buy seperate copies of Minecraft, again and again simply for a feature that bedrock has at the get go. A feature that is at deficit because of it's modless nature.

Comment: If you have three accounts, of course you can use those all at once. Which PC that runs on doesn't matter.

Comment: I meant by three of the same in THREE of the SAME account. just changes the name of the player. I've tried posting to Mojangs help over whether this is allowed because I'm sick of playing boring vanilla splitscreen.

Comment: I think then it's not allowed, you're supposed to use different accounts for different players. Regular Minecraft servers even don't allow it.

Comment: They're on the same computer, my own at home. I've sent a message to one of the developers to clear things up. I kinda of thought to myself If I used their account on my pc wouldn't that also break the TOS too because my computer is using their profile?

Comment: No, I'm using two accounts on my computer as well. And I used to use one account on two of three computers, they were all my own. The purpose of these rules is just that you don't share your account with other people.

Comment: was the rule in the EULA in place as a sort of data protection? I'm just confused. I just find it odd that you can't share a Java account but you can share a copy of the bedrock edition.

Comment: You also can't share that copy. Otherwise you could just buy one copy and send it to everyone on the planet.

Comment: Thank you for the replies, I think we should end this conversation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no lawyer, but it's best to say that it is ***against*** the EULA (https://account.mojang.com/documents/minecraft_eula) to play splitscreen on PC with friends.

You see, the EULA states that "When you buy our Game, you receive a license that gives you permission to install the Game on your own ***personal device*** and use and play it on that device as set out in this EULA"

When you buy the game, it gives you the "right" to download and play it on your ***personal device***. As long as it is on your personal device, it is completely OK to do anything you desire with it. That applies to your friends too. They also have the right to play it ***ONLY on their own personal device***.

It also says that "This also means you cannot sell or rent the Game, or ***make it available*** ***for access to other people*** and you cannot pass on or resell any license keys"

Now this section states that it can't be made available for people who have not bought the game. Since your friends have bought Bedrock Edition, you have a reason to say it's legal.

But, I would not say that it's legal. Your friends have bought a completely different version for a completely different price. They are to download it on their personal device and only use it on their personal device. Buying one version of the game does not entitle them to having the right to play on any of the other versions.

And playing splitscreen is actually taking advantage of a vulnerability in the game, as you are taking advantage of the fact that you can "change the name of the player" in notepad (in the source code). That is considered exploiting, and you will probably get your licence to play the game terminated, along with other penalties.

So if you don't want to get into any legal trouble, I suggest you assume that it is illegal to play splitscreen on Minecraft Java Edition with friends.

Comment: It's just a shame with that Bedrock edition has splitscreen integrated into it whilst PC doesn't, so there is no other option.  I did look on another thread and one of the people of Mojang were fine about family sharing. Should I try contacting someone from their company?

Comment: If you are desperate to play splitscreen on PC, you may do so. If you're "family sharing" on Bedrock, I'm pretty sure it's fine, but on PC, you're only meant to run one instance of the game at a time. Playing splitscreen on PC, from my research, would be called "exploiting" as it is not an intended feature. But as mentioned earlier, if you're desperate to play splitscreen on PC, contact Mojang about it.